# Why doesn't my Python tkinter Checkbox appear?

Tags: python, tkinter

so I tried putting a  checkbox into my tkinter window with this code:

```
def a():
    if checkbutton.get():
        print("Checkbox is chosen")
    else:
        print("Checkbox ist not chosen")


checkbutton = IntVar(Checkbutton)
checkbutton =
Checkbutton(self=checkbutton,master=root,text="Pyhon3",variable=checkbutton,command=a)
checkbutton.pack()
```

and That generated this error:

```
File "C:\Users\ulric\Desktop\Tkinter.py", line 63, in <module>
    checkbutton = IntVar(Checkbutton)
TypeError: _root() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I don't know what to pass in for "self"...
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntVar()` does not take a class as a parameter which is what caused the problem. Also either change the variable or check button name or the program will throw another error saying the checkbutton attribute does not have a get() method. I added an "n" to the checkbutton object but you can change this if you wish.

```
def a():
    if checkbutton.get():
        print("Checkbox is chosen")
    else:
        print("Checkbox ist not chosen")


checkbutton = IntVar()
checkbuttonn = Checkbutton(root,text="Pyhon3",variable=checkbutton,command=a)
checkbuttonn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"IntVar() does not take any parameters"_ - that's not entirely true. It takes parameters, but it doesn't take a class as a parameter.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for clarifying. I'll update the answer with that